# Getting calclated values from mpu 9150

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer

for a school project we got a mpu 9150 (Gyro/Accelerometer/Magnetometer(?)) and we want to get Roll/Pitch/Yaw/Heading for it.

I used a code that was as an example in the libary, but it gives us only the raw datas in that format: ax/ay/az/gx/gy/gz/mx/my/mz. Thats not what we want.

I managed to get roll and pitch so far with the following snippet:

```
roll = atan2(ay, az)+PI;
pitch = atan2(-ax, az)+PI;

// Convert everything from radians to degrees:
pitch *= 180.0 / PI;
roll  *= 180.0 / PI;
```

And i read that i have to use the magnetometer to get the yaw, but i have no idea what formular i need for it.

In the example code there is also this snippet inside, maybe thats all i need to use or anyone knows other functions/methods i could use?

```
// read raw accel/gyro measurements from device
accelgyro.getMotion9(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz, &mx, &my, &mz);

// these methods (and a few others) are also available
//accelgyro.getAcceleration(&ax, &ay, &az);
//accelgyro.getRotation(&gx, &gy, &gz);
```

I working with the I2Cdev and MPU6050 libaries

Another question would be, what kind of things can i get from the sensor else? Is it possible to get the height or difference in height of it?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raw values of your mpu are mostly very inexact, drifting away, ... not really usable. The MPU6050 libary is very useful to get useful values. To get your yaw/roll/pitch you could use the MPU6050 Libary like the example described in this [example sketch](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/blob/master/Arduino/MPU6050/Examples/MPU6050_DMP6/MPU6050_DMP6.ino). Just add

```
#define OUTPUT_READABLE_YAWPITCHROLL
```

on top this code an run it (with the right baudrate).

With your sensor it´s also possible to get the actual temperature.

Comment: With the 1 code snippet above the values of pitch/roll seem to be stabe (dont change at 1 degree). I only have to use that example code with that define snippet? ps.: is german talking also allowed? then i would understand more :D

Comment: I think german is not favored here ... but: ja, einfach den define reinnehmen, richtige Baudrate einstellen, Arduino richtig verkabeln, und es sollte dein Ergebnis rauskommen :-) ... yes, use the define, take the right baudrate, wire and ready :-)

Comment: ok, then try it in english :D it worked so far: only that the yaw is counting the whole time, even i dont change the position. And can i test if the sensor is moving (back/forward/height) and how fast? should be possible right? in that case i have to define the other things, that are currently commented(?) ?

Comment: Right. Just define the part you want. If you want the euler angles, add #define OUTPUT_READABLE_EULER. Your second problem, try to calibrate your mpu. Here is a sketch: http://www.i2cdevlib.com/forums/topic/112-another-auto-offset-calibration-sketch/